# Is tabindex feature there in xforms?

Tags: xforms, orbeon

I was doing my unit testing for the form, and found out that there is some serious problem with the automatic tab index that Orbeon gives.

In my case I have the need for following tab indexes 1-7 as shown by number in the figure.

Model:

```
<xforms:model>
    <xforms:instance id="dropdown-values">
        <form>
           <yes-no>
             <options>Yes</options>
             <options>No</options>
          </yes-no>
       </form>
    </xforms:instance>
</xforms:model>
```

Logic to create the radio in form:

```
<xforms:itemset nodeset="instance('dropdown-values')/yes-no/options">
    <xforms:label ref="." />
    <xforms:value ref="." />
</xforms:itemset>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QvKq.jpg]

The example above has a functionality like when "No" is selected in the "Enable text" option, the following text-boxes are disabled. Currently Orbeon is providing a default tabindex and switching from selected radio button to the next field. I.e.:

- if radio is selected as "no", the navigation using tab will be 2->6 and repeat
- if radio is selected as "Yes", the navigation using tab will be 1->3->4->5->7 and repeat

But the functionality intended is:

- if radio is selected as "no", the navigation using tab will be 1->2->5->6 then repeat.
- if radio is selected as "Yes", the navigation using tab will be 1->2->3->4->5->6->7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this well, you want tabbing to be done in the order in which the controls are in the page. The issue is that when you tab through radio buttons:

- You observe that the "cursor" goes subsequently to each radio button.
- You would like it to go to the next field.

I am not sure what browser you are using, as when I try this, if a radio button is selected at all time, the cursor doesn't go through all the radio buttons, but just to the one you selected. That is, I am getting the "what you would like", not the "what you observe" behavior. I tested this with Firefox 4 and IE 7.

BTW, this behavior has nothing to do with XForms; this is just how tabbing works through HTML controls.

[image: Tabs on Firefox 4]

Answer (score 1):

XForms provides the `navindex` attribute for this purpose, defined in [section 8.1, The XForms Core Form Controls Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms11/#def-core-form-control):

> ...a non-negative integer in the
>   range of 0-32767 used to define the
>   navigation sequence. This gives the
>   author control over the sequence in
>   which form controls are traversed.

There is also further discussion of some of the finer points related to `navindex` navigation in [section 4.3.6, The xforms-next and xforms-previous Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms11/#evt-next).

Comment: The navindex seems to be the equivalent to html tabindex. But there is not enough documentation on usage with xforms:itemset. Still, Thanks for sharing a direction for the solution for my problem.